# Heat map from data file

Tags: plotting, data

I have a file with data arranged in the following way:

> ...
>
> 0.051 0.056 0.269639
>
> 0.051 0.057 0.252626
>
> 0.051 0.058 0.23856
>
> ...

I'd like to plot an heat map and I've managed something like this:

```
ListDensityPlot[  Import["\HeatMap.txt", "Data"],   PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> Hue]
```

Wich gives me:

[image: Heat Map]

The problem is that I don't know what the colors are corresponding to in terms of values. Can I mark colors for specific value ranges? Or how can I find out how the color gradient is comparing to the values?

Also, there is a particular point of interest in the data, how can I show it?

Comment: "colors for specific value ranges" - why not use `Blend[]`? "find out how the color gradient is comparing to the values" - that's what legends are for, no?

Comment: Of course, I just wasn't aware how to add them. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ListDensityPlot[{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 
   4}}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Yellow, Red}, #] &)]
```

Generates labels where the values in the plot range between Yellow and Red.

You can check the colour for the scale:

```
Blend[{Yellow, Red}, 0.5]
```

For instance gives the colour for the median value.
[image]

This epilogue finds the lowest value, (which in this case is of course not unique, but I needed an easy dataset)

```
data = Table[
   With[{r = RandomReal[{0, 5}], 
     t = RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}]}, {r Cos[t], r Sin[t], 
     Sin[r^2]/r^2}], {10^4}];
ListDensityPlot[data, PlotRange -> All, 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Yellow, Red}, #] &), 
 Epilog -> {Black, PointSize -> 0.01, 
 Point[Flatten[MinimalBy[data, Last]][[1 ;; 2]]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know how I can mark specific point?

Comment: @phytab I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: In your picture, let's say I wanted to mark the point (2.0,2.0) with a black dot. How could I do that? Or have it always mark the (x,y) that gives the lowest z for example.

Comment: @phytab You could do something like `{Black, Yellow, Yellow, Orange, Orange, Red, Red}`, or say `{Yellow, Yellow, Black, Orange, Orange, Red, Red}` to have a small band at $3/7\pm 1/14$ at the range of values be black.

Comment: @phytab, you can use `Epilog` to add a `Point[]`.

Comment: `,Epilog -> {Black, Point[{2, 2}]}` Or a function that finds the point with `MinimalBy`

Comment: Got it working, I thank you both.

Comment: @phytab Ok, and here I had just finished my example :), I'll add it anyway.

Comment: @Feyre +1 Nice answer, returning the favor